# QueryRecord returns error while using attributes (Apache NiFi)

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a simple FlowFile which contains JSON:

```
{
  "name" : "ga:sessions",
  "val" : "0"
}
```

And some attributes:

```
account.login = "some_email@gmail.com"
account.id = "123456789"
```

I want to use `QueryRecord` processor to prepare JSON for saving into database.
[image: processor]

But I get an error:

[image: error]

`QueryRecord` successfully set `account_login` from attribute but returns error. What is the problem? If I will not use attributes in `QueryRecord` SQL statement, I'll not get an error:

```
[{
  "metric_name" : "ga:sessions",
  "metric_value" : "0"
}]
```

How to solve it?

Comment: I am confused by this part in query to add the email...  I think you need to do the select from the flowfile, to get those results in the flowfile - which is actually no different than the original flowfile.  Assuming you have a larger upstream data set, the query should dial that down to results you want.  Then after that add the email value to flowfile with another processor....  I believe the root cause is that the SQL inside the flowfile query is limited in functionality.

Comment: I used `QueryRecord` before in the same way, but now it doesn't work. You can prepare JSON with Expression Language and put attributes to content. But i just used `JoltTransform` instead and all works fine.

Comment: I tried to do it yesterday to add a string or attribute in the left side of the select and it definitely did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for QueryRecord to recognize the literal string value in the query, you should use apostrophes.

Your query should look like this:

```
SELECT name AS metric_name,
val AS metric_value,
'${account.login}' as account_login
FROM FLOWFILE
```